# Configuring source code of Python on Eclipse

Tags: python, c, eclipse

I wonder does someone work with source code of Python on Eclipse/Linux? I have imported it as a makefile project, it builds OK, but error parsers cannot correctly parse some definitions and produce plenty of semantic errors like this:

```
Field 'Py_DECREF(argtuple)' could not be resolved
```

I checked that field (it is a macro in `Include/object.h`) and it seems the error is because the macro uses a struct that is not yet defined (it is defined in `pyport.h` which is not included in `object.h`). I created the following project:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "/mnt/proj/c/Python-3.4.3/Include/pyport.h"
#include "/mnt/proj/c/Python-3.4.3/Include/object.h"

int main(void) {
    PyObject po;
    Py_DECREF(&po);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles OK and error parsers parse it OK. I removed two last includes and added those two files to `Project/Properties/Preprocessor Include Paths/CDT User Setting Entries`. Error parsers parse it OK (without those two headers added, Py_DECREF produces "not resolved" error). I tried to do the same in the Python project (I have added to CDT User Setting Entries `pyport.h` and `object.h` headers), but that's not corrected errors.

What configuration settings must be created in order to get rid of those semantic errors?

**EDIT 1:**

The parser log is filled with entries like this:

```
Attempt to use symbol failed: tp_dealloc in file /mnt/proj/c/Python-3.4.3/Python/bltinmodule.c:416
Attempt to use symbol failed: ob_type in file /mnt/proj/c/Python-3.4.3/Python/bltinmodule.c:417
Attempt to use symbol failed: tp_free in file /mnt/proj/c/Python-3.4.3/Python/bltinmodule.c:417
Attempt to use symbol failed: ob_type in file /mnt/proj/c/Python-3.4.3/Python/bltinmodule.c:436
Attempt to use symbol failed: tp_iternext in file /mnt/proj/c/Python-3.4.3/Python/bltinmodule.c:436
Attempt to use symbol failed: ob_refcnt in file /mnt/proj/c/Python-3.4.3/Python/bltinmodule.c:449
```

Those symbols are related to `_typeobject` structure defined in `object.h`.  The definition of that structure uses `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` macro, defined in the same file as follows:

```
#define PyObject_VAR_HEAD      PyVarObject ob_base;
```

But `PyVarObject` structure is defined several lines AFTER the `PyObject_VAR_HEAD`. Couldn't it cause those errors?

Comment: It’s true that `object.h` doesn’t include `pyport.h`, but I arbitrarily picked a Python source file and it includes `Python.h`, which includes both `pyport.h` and `object.h`, so as long as you’re including `Python.h` rather than individual header files, you should be OK.

Comment: Unfortunately including `Python.h` doesn't correct errors. However, I edited the post with some additional info.

Comment: If Eclipse is complaining that a macro uses things that aren’t defined, Eclipse is in the wrong, since macros are expanded at their *use site*, **not** their definition site.

Comment: Eclipse says that 'attempt to use symbol failed'. Why it's failed - isn't clear. I asked in the hope that someone works with Python on Eclipse and knows what configuration should be done.